# Using SpriteBatch with Direct3D and XAML

Tags: c++, xaml, directx, spritebatch

I have created a project that runs on Windows Phone 8 that uses the template Direct3D With XAML provided by the Windows Phone SDK. I have also incorporated DirectXTK and declared a `std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> m_SB;` in the CubeRenderer.h

When I try to assign it in the function CreateDeviceResources thus:

```
m_SB.reset(new SpriteBatch(m_d3dContext.Get()));
```

it gives the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.

I do not know why this is. This works perfectly if I create the project with the Direct3D (Native) template.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the code inside the `CreateWindowSizeDependentResources` function, then it should work fine.

[Source](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/discussions/443692)